# Access Query getting error 3141

Tags: sql, ms-access-2003

I am working in Access 2003

I am trying to create a query that will create a table that is already in the exact format my excel sheet needs to be in.  I figured this would save me time in the long rather than creating the table, then writing the code to insert values, offset cells, insert more, etc all in a giant loop.  This way I create the table the way I need it and then just dump it to excel.

The issue I am getting is the below query gets the following error:

Run-time error '3141';
The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect.

```
DoCmd.RunSQL ("SELECT [Main Employee Table].SSN, [Main Employee Table].[LastName] AS [Last Name], [Main Employee Table].[FirstName] AS [First Name], " _
        & "[Main Employee Table].[MiddleName] AS [Middle Intial], " _
        & "[Address Table].[Address] AS [Address Line 1], Null AS [Address Line 2] [City] AS Ciity, " _
        & "UCase([State]) AS Sstate, Format([ZipCode],""00000"") AS [Zip Code], Null AS TaxState, " _
        & """20141201"" AS [Chk Request Date], [Main Employee Table].DOB AS [Date of Birth], " _
        & "IIf(([Status]='Beneficiary' Or [Status]='Beneficiary/late'),""05"",IIf([Status]='QDRO/TV',""01"",""00"")) AS RelationshipCode, " _
        & "Null AS [Lump Sum Benefit L], tblLSWindow.LSRollOver AS [Rollover Benefit R], " _
        & "Null AS [Partial Benefit P], Null AS [Hardship Benefit H], Null AS [Min Req Distr Benefit M], Null AS [Nontaxable Benefit], " _
        & "tblLSWindow.LSRollOver AS [Total], ""R"" AS [Distribution Suffix], Null AS [Marital Status], " _
        & """1"" AS [Federal Withholding Switch], ""1"" AS [State Withholding Switch], Null AS [Federal Exemp Number], ""0"" AS [Federal Additional Amount], " _
        & "Null AS [State Exemp Number], ""0"" AS [State Additional Amount], ""G"" AS [Distribution Code], " _
        & "[RollOverInstitution] AS [Rollover Institution Name Address Line 1], [FirstName] & "" "" & [Last Name] AS [FBO Address Line 2], " _
        & "[Address] AS [Rollover Institution Address Line 3], [City] AS [Rollover Institution City], [State] AS [Rollover Institution State], " _
        & "[ZipCode] AS [Rollover Institution Zip Code] " _
        & "INTO AutoCashLoadReport " _
        & "FROM ([Main Employee Table] LEFT JOIN tblLSWindow " _
        & "ON [Main Employee Table].SSN = tblLSWindow.SSN) " _
        & "LEFT JOIN [Address Table] ON [Main Employee Table].SSN = [Address Table].SSN " _
        & "WHERE ((tblLSWindow.LSRollOver>0) AND ([tblLSWindow].[IGOChk]=-1))")
```

Now I realize that it is very bad form to use tables with spaces in them, but this is a very old database and I haven't wanted to go in and mess with it at all.

I haven't been able to figure out what is wrong with this code.  I've been looking for missing commas, or brackets I forgot to close, etc, but I haven't had any luck finding anything.  I originally had constant items (items like "1" or "G", etc) with single quotes around them, but I've changed them to two double quotes thinking it might be the problem.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Using some formatting would make this about a million time easier to read. You are missing a comma between two of your columns. Null AS [Address Line 2] [City] AS Ciity,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `,` in the below line

```
Null AS [Address Line 2] [City] AS Ciity
                        <--Here
```

Comment: That was it.  I can't believe I didn't find that one.  Thank you for the help!